# 2000s (?) movie/TV show where music makes white foam come out of people's ears

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

When I was younger (20-15 years ago), I accidentally watched something on TV where there's a group of people at a party, dancing. A person comes in with a boombox and turns on his music, which causes people to die, with foam coming out of their ears.

This scared me at the time, and it has stayed with me but I've never been able to identify what it actually was. It came on after some evening game show, and it probably wasn't meant for me as a kid. Because of this, the scene was probably at the start of the show/movie.

I don't remember anyone talking at all, but it might have been a Swedish show, in which case I suppose it's a lot harder to identify.

Comment: You have a good start here but did you watch anything else of this to know any other plot points you can [edit] in? Do you know the main character, what did they look like?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Yeah that's the thing, I know this is really vague, but it's all I've got. The only other thing I can add was that this scene was probably at the start of the show/movie, since I just continued watching TV after the last show.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is part of a Swedish sketch show called "[En Himla Många Program](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_himla_m%C3%A5nga_program_(TV-serie))". It was originally aired on December 31 1996. The sketch is called "Allsångsmördaren".

The scene in question can be found here: